# React Native: dim background of modal screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-modal

How can I dim the background of my modal? I'm using a stack navigator with mode modal for clarity. I've managed to get the background to be transparent but not sure how to dim the background screen. Here is my stack navigator code:

```
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Home from '../components/home/Home';
import Settings from '../components/settings/Settings';

const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Home,
    },
    Settings: {
      screen: Settings,
      navigationOptions: {
        gestureResponseDistance: {vertical: 800},
      },
    },
  },
  {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
    transparentCard: true,
  },
);

export default AppStack;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add another property of `opacity` in your code to the cardStyle. You can read more about it in a similar github issue raised here. https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7085

```
 {
mode: "modal",
headerMode: "none",
transparentCard: true,
defaultNavigationOptions: {
  gesturesEnabled: false
},
cardStyle: {
  // makes transparentCard work for android
  opacity: 1.0
}
```